# CTRL+F keyboardEvent not opening find

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keyboard-events

I'm trying to programmatically open find with `keyboardEvent` ,but its not opening it. I get the event in the console,so I'm a bit confused is it even possible to do?

Here's the code:

```
const openFind = () => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        console.log(e)
      });
      document.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { key: '70',code:'70', ctrlKey: true ,bubbles:true}));
};
```

I'm triggering it `onClick`.

And this is what I get in the console:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to open the browser's "find in page" functionality? Because I don't think this is possible.

Comment: @VLAZ  That's what I want.

Comment: OK, in that case, I don't think it's possible. You're issuing that code from the page, whereas you are trying to invoke browser level functionality. Browsers separate page code from browser operation and try to avoid exposing their own operation. There is [`window.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find) but it's not standard and it doesn't (or isn't guaranteed) to open the "find in page" panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find is what you are looking for, but it isn't supported on most browsers.

Only solution is to implement your own search bar and not use the native one.

Comment: Yes, I know this one, its not working on chrome, or at least it didn't work for me..

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done.

It is obvious that chrome wouldn't just hand you an API to control things like search dialog, bookmarking, control over other tabs, dev tools, ...etc. Unless you're using Selenium for automation testing or making an extension.